# как настроить мониторинг Java приложения в Zabbix?

Tags: java, zabbix, jmx

Есть примитивное приложение Java:

```
public class SimpleAgent
{
    private MBeanServer mbs = null;

    public SimpleAgent()
    {
        // Получить экземпляр MBeanServer
        mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

        // Создаем наш MBean
        Hello helloBean = new Hello();
        ObjectName helloName = null;

        try {
            // И регистрируем его на платформе MBeanServer
            helloName = new ObjectName("SimpleAgent:name=hellothere");
            mbs.registerMBean(helloBean, helloName);

            // Теперь мы регистрируем коннектор, который
            // будет доступен по HTTP-протоколу


        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Это вспомогательный метод - он позволяет нашей программе остановиться и ждать
    private static void waitForEnterPressed()
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Press  to continue...");
            System.in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        SimpleAgent agent = new SimpleAgent();
        System.out.println("SimpleAgent is running...");
        SimpleAgent.waitForEnterPressed();
    }
}

public interface HelloMBean {
    public void setMessage(String message);
    public String getMessage();
    public void sayHello();
}

public class Hello implements HelloMBean{
    private String message = null;

    public Hello() {
        message = "Hello there";
    }

    public Hello(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

запускаю со следующими параметрами:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -cp . SimpleAgent
```

запустил в Docker Zabbix сервер и Zabbix Java Gateway(Gateway на порту 10052)

На сервере настраиваю Items
[image: Items]
[image: Host]

Но как видно на скриншотах, JMX светится красным и пишет

> Connection refused (Connection refused):
>   service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:12345/jmxrmi

Подскажите пожалуйста, где искать ошибку? Может какие настройки пропустил?

Comment: а у Вас сам jmxcp.jar запущен?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, а что это? В документации нигде не встречал